Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(u_k+u_{k+1})^2=2u_1^2 \frac{r^{2n-1}-1}{r-1}-(u_1^2+u_n^2)$, where $u_{k+1}=ru_k$
I recently found this question whilst doing some basic math practice.
Suppose $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n$ is a geometric sequence with common ratio $r$. Show that $$(u_1+u_2)^2+(u_2+u_3)^2+(u_3+u_4)^2+\cdots+(u_{n-1}+u_n)^2=2u_1^2 \frac{r^{2n-1}-1}{r-1}-(u_1^2+u_n^2)$$
To keep things short, I managed to prove it but my method feels very "brute force"-ish.
This is what I did:
First, show that the LHS itself is a geometric series as follows:
$$
(u_1 + u_2)^2 + (u_2 + u_3)^2 + (u_3 + u_4)^2 + \dots + (u_{n-1} + u_n)^2 \\
$$
$$
= a^2_1 + a^2_2 + a^2_3 + \dots + a^2_{n-1} 
$$
where
$$
a_1 = u_1 + u_2 = u_1 + u_1r = u_1(1 + r) 
$$
Similarly:
$$\begin{align}
a_2 &= u_1(1 + r)r \\
a_3 &= u_1(1 + r)r^2 \\
&\vdots \\
a_{n-1} &= u_1(1 + r)r^{n-2}
\end{align}
$$
And so we end up with the LHS neatly wrapped up as such:
$$
S_{n-1} = u^2_1(1 + r)^2 \cdot \frac{(r^{2(n-1)} - 1)}{r^2 -1}
$$
However, I couldn't see a way in which I could easily get this side to equal the RHS. What I did was essentially "butcher" each side by fully expanding and seeing that you end up with the same mess both sides, I.E. this:
$$
u^2_1 \frac {(r^{2n} + 2r^{2n-1} + r^{2n-2} - r^2 - 2r - 1)}{r^2 - 1}
$$
But I don't see how I could neatly manipulate the LHS to arrive at the equation on the RHS.
Any suggestions?

One alternative approach is to note $u_k=u_1 r^{k-1}$ so $u_k^2=u_1^2 r^{2k-2}$ and $u_ku_{k+1} =u_1^2 r^{2k-1}$ so
$$\begin{align}
 & (u_1+u_2)^2+(u_2+u_3)^2+\cdots+(u_{n-1}+u_n)^2 \\
=& (u_1^2+2u_1u_2+u_2^2)+(u_2^2+2u_2u_3+u_3^2)+\cdots+(u_{n-1}^2+2u_{n-1}u_n+u_n^2)\\
=& u_1^2+2u_1u_2+2u_2^2+2u_2u_3+2u_3^2+\cdots+2u_{n-1}^2+2u_{n-1}u_n+u_n^2\\
=& 2(u_1^2+u_1u_2+u_2^2+u_2u_3+u_3^2+\cdots+u_{n-1}^2+u_{n-1}u_n+u_n^2) -(u_1^2+u_n^2)\\
=& 2u_1^2(1+r+r^2+r^3+r^4+\cdots+r^{2n-4}+r^{2n-3}+r^{2n-2}) -(u_1^2+u_n^2)\\
=& 2u_1^2\frac{r^{2n-1}-1}{r-1} -(u_1^2+u_n^2).\\
\end{align}$$

This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!!!

Let $u_1 = u$. Consider \begin{align}
&(u_1 + u_2)^2 + (u_2 + u_3)^2 + (u_3 + u_4)^2 + \dots + (u_{n-1} + u_n)^2 + (u_1^2+u_n^2) \\
=& u^2(1+r)^2 + u^2 r^2(1+r)^2+...+u^2r^{2(n-2)}(1+r)^2 + u^2(1+r^{2(n-1)})\\
=& u^2(1+r)^2\{ 1+r^2+...+r^{2(n-2)} \} + u^2(1+r^{2(n-1)}) \\ 
=& u^2(1+r)^2 \big\{ \frac{ r^{2(n-1) }-1 }{ r^2-1 } \big\}+ u^2(1+r^{2(n-1)}) \\ 
=& u^2 \frac{ -2+2r^{2n} + 2r^{2n-1} - 2r }{r^2-1}\\
=& 2 u^2 \frac{ (r+1)(2r^{2n-1}-2) }{ (r-1)(r+1) }.
\end{align}
We obtain the required result.

If $r=-1$, the equality resumes to $0=0$. Assume henceforth $r\ne-1$ and also (which is implicit in the question) $r\ne1$.
The sequence $$b_i:=(x_i+x_{i+1})^2$$
is geometric, with ratio
$r^2$ and first term $b_1=u_1^2(1+r)^2$.
Your LHS is
$$b_1+b_2+\dots+b_{n-1}=b_1\frac{r^{2(n-1)}-1}{r^2-1}=u_1^2(1+r)\frac{r^{2n-2}-1}{r-1}.$$
Your RHS was
$$u_1^2\left(2\frac{r^{2n-1}-1}{r-1}-1-r^{2(n-1)}\right),$$ which can now easily been checked to be equal to the LHS.


Suppose $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n$ is a geometric sequence with common ratio $r$. Show that $$(u_1+u_2)^2+(u_2+u_3)^2+(u_3+u_4)^2+\cdots+(u_{n-1}+u_n)^2=2u_1^2 \frac{r^{2n-1}-1}{r-1}-(u_1^2+u_n^2)$$

From the original assertion, you can assume, without loss of generality, that $~r \neq 1.$
From the Original Poster's own work, the LHS equals
$$u^2_1(1 + r)^2 \cdot \frac{(r^{2(n-1)} - 1)}{r^2 -1}
= u^2_1(1 + r) \cdot \frac{(r^{2(n-1)} - 1)}{r-1}
$$
$$= \frac{u^2_1}{r-1} \left[ ~r^{2n-1} + r^{2n-2} - r - 1 ~\right]. \tag1 $$
The RHS simplifies to
$$u^2_1 \left[ ~\frac{2 (r^{2n-1}-1)}{r-1} - (1 + r^{2n-2}) ~\right]$$
$$=\frac{u^2_1}{r-1} \left\{ ~(2r^{2n-1} - 2) - \left[ ~(r - 1) (1 + r^{2n-2})~\right]  ~\right\}
$$
$$=\frac{u^2_1}{r-1} \left\{ ~(2r^{2n-1} - 2) - 
\left[ ~r - 1 + r^{2n-1} - r^{2n-2} ~\right] ~\right\}$$
$$=\frac{u^2_1}{r-1} \left\{r^{2n-1} + r^{2n-2} - r - 1 ~\right\}. \tag2 $$
The expressions in (1) and (2) above match.
